# MIPS merge sort recursion

Tags: sorting, merge, mips

I need to write  a MIPS assembly language code for merge sort. I have already created the merge function but the merge_sort function that uses recursion extensively confuses me. I have posted the reference C code for the same. I understand that stacks will have to be used, however, unable to do it myself being a beginner, I would appreciate any kind of help.

```
int merge_sort(int arr[],int low,int high)
{
  int mid;
  if(low<high) {
mid=(low+high)/2;
// Divide and Conquer
merge_sort(arr,low,mid);
merge_sort(arr,mid+1,high);
// Combine
merge(arr,low,mid,high);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you convert simple non-recursive C functions into MIPS?

Answer (score 0):

Why not go from the bottom up and first `merge` pairs of singletons, then pairs of already sorted 2-length sub-arrays, then pairs of 4-length sub-arrays, etc., `log n` passes over same array, in a loop?

The problem remaining is to implement `merge`. It will be called repeatedly, but not recursively. This `merge` will of course have to write its output back into the array over the input area, perhaps making a temporary copy of its input to work over.

```
void mrgsort( int a[], int n) // pseudo-code
{
    if( n < 1 ) return;
    int s1 = 1, s2 = 2;
    do
    {
        int i, k = n/s2, p1=0, p2=s1;
        for( i=0; i<k; ++i, p1+=s2, p2+=s2 )
        {
            merge(p1, p2); // merge chunks of size s1
        }
        //  deal with the edge ...
        if( i > 0 )
        {
            if( p2 < n ) merge_edge(p1,p2,n); // 2nd chunk shorter
        }
        s1 = s2;
        s2 = s2*2;
    } while( s2 <= n )
    if( s1 < n )
        merge_edge(0,s1,n);                   // 2nd chunk shorter
}
```

No recursion, just one loop.

Comment: I did think of it that way but implementing it in MIPS is giving a little trouble. 
yes, merge is not the problem here rather merge_sort(has the recursion part). The merge logic is easily converted into assembly code.

Comment: but it doesn't *have* to be recursive. You just loop scanning over the array while increasing the unit size.